# Tkinter scrollable frame cut off when adding horizontal scrollbar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm modifying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985165/9976891) example to add a horizontal scrollbar. I've looked at similar answers on SO but they don't help, which I'll explain further at the bottom of the question.

Before adding the horizontal scrollbar, I added some code that instead of a single column of buttons, adds a grid of buttons:

```
for i in range(30):
for j in range(30):
    new_button = ttk.Button(
        master=scrollable_body,
        text="Button " + str(i) + ", " + str(j)
    )
    new_button.grid(
        column=j,
        row=i
    )
```

This works exactly as one would expect (of course with no horizontal scrollbar as I haven't added it yet):

[image]

However, if I modify the `Scrollable` class to add a horizontal scrollbar like so:

```
class Scrollable(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, frame, width=8):

    scrollbar_v = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width)
    scrollbar_v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y, expand=False)

    scrollbar_h = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width, orient="horizontal")
    scrollbar_h.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X, expand=False)

    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_v.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_h.set)
    self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    scrollbar_v.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
    scrollbar_h.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

    self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.__fill_canvas)

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, frame)

    self.windows_item = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self, anchor=tk.NW)

def __fill_canvas(self, event):
    canvas_width = event.width
    canvas_height = event.height
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.windows_item, width=canvas_width)
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.windows_item, height=canvas_height)

def update(self):
    self.update_idletasks()
    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.windows_item))
```

The the buttons are cut off when scrolling:

[image]

There are similar questions on SO but they haven't helped.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59530435/9976891) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26216359/9976891) suggest using `.grid()` method with the `sticky=` argument, but that didn't work. Changing the part of `__init__()` that adds the widgets to use `.grid()` instead of `.pack()` did not change the outcome whatsoever:

```
scrollbar_v = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width)
    scrollbar_v.grid(
        column=1,
        row=0,
        rowspan=2,
        sticky=(tk.N, tk.S)
    )

    scrollbar_h = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width, orient="horizontal")
    scrollbar_h.grid(
        column=0,
        row=1,
        columnspan=2,
        sticky=(tk.W, tk.E)
    )

    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_v.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_h.set)
    self.canvas.grid(
        column=0,
        row=0,
        sticky=(tk.N, tk.E, tk.S, tk.W)
    )
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33575534/9976891) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17690152/9976891) suggests the answer may be to do with using `self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))` instead, but that didn't work either.

I feel the answer may be to do with the line `self.windows_item = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self, anchor=tk.NW)`, but I don't understand how that's wrong - I thought the NW anchor would make sure it worked?

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] as currently the posted code does not show how the instance of `Scrollable` is created.

Comment: Try using `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` on the `Tk` window. This should enable the canvas to expand to fill the window.

Comment: What do you mean buttons cut-off when scrolling? I mean, it seems OK, since user scroll and buttons are not moving with scrolling! Do you expect to see all buttons while user scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cut down version of your code that seems to solve the problem.

The truncated buttons problem is solved by using `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` on `app`.
This enables a grid object (canvas) to stick to the app window during resizing.

The other problem is using a class to create a frame.
This is due to frame (F) being the child of app when it needs to be the child of canvas.
This fix prevents buttons from covering the scrollbars.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('548x266')

app.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
app.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

V = tk.Scrollbar(app, width=12)
V.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.NS)

H = tk.Scrollbar(app, width=12, orient="horizontal")
H.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.EW)

canvas = tk.Canvas(
    app,
    # fix artifacts problem when scrolling
    xscrollincrement = 76, yscrollincrement = 25,
    xscrollcommand = H.set, yscrollcommand = V.set)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

V.config(command=canvas.yview)
H.config(command=canvas.xview)

F = tk.Frame(canvas)

for i in range(30):
    for j in range(30):
        b = ttk.Button(master=F, text=f"Button {i:02d},{j:02d}")
        b.grid(column = j, row = i)

F.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all")))

W = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=F, anchor=tk.NW)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. As for your second point: you are correct. For making a class, it seems it would be correct to create a child class of `Canvas` that itself contains a `Frame` object, instead of a child class of `Frame` that is within (or contains) a `Canvas` object. That is what I will do.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at how the vertical scrolling options worked and didn't really like them. Since your buttons are arranged in a table, I tried using `ttk.Treeview`. Clicking on a cell simulates clicking on a button. And there are no problems with scrolling.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

COLS = 30
ROWS = 30


def select_cell(event):
    """ Determine which table cell was clicked."""
    iid = table.identify_row(event.y)
    selected_col = table.identify_column(event.x)
    value = table.set(iid, selected_col)
    table.set(iid, selected_col, 'Click')
    lbl_header.config(text=f'Cell clicked {value}', font=20, foreground='red')
    table.after(300, lambda: table.set(iid, selected_col, value))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

style = ttk.Style()

style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=45, font='bold')
print(style.map('Treeview'))
style.map('Treeview',
            background=[('disabled', 'SystemButtonFace'), ('selected', 'SystemButtonFace')],
            foreground=[('disabled', 'SystemGrayText'), ('selected', 'SystemGrayText')])
style.configure('Header.TFrame', background='green4')
style.configure('Footer.TFrame', background='brown4')

header = ttk.Frame(root, style='Header.TFrame')
body = ttk.Frame(root)
footer = ttk.Frame(root, style='Footer.TFrame')

header.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
body.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
footer.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

lbl_header = ttk.Label(header, text="The Header")
lbl_footer = ttk.Label(footer, text="The Footer")

lbl_footer.pack(pady=20)
lbl_header.pack(pady=20)

# Fill the table cells with dough - button such and such.
cols = tuple(f'{col}' for col in range(COLS))

table = ttk.Treeview(body, columns=cols, show='', selectmode='browse')
button = []
for row in range(ROWS + 1):
    if button:
        if row % 2:
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=button, tags='color_1')
        else:
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=button, tags='color_2')
        button = []

    for col in range(COLS):
        button.append(f'button {col} - {row}')
        if not row:
            table.column(column=f'{col}', width=125, stretch=False)

# We make it possible to scroll the table.
scrollbar_horizontal = ttk.Scrollbar(body, orient='horizontal', command=table.xview)
scrollbar_vertical = ttk.Scrollbar(body, orient='vertical', command=table.yview)
table.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_vertical.set)
table.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar_horizontal.set)

scrollbar_vertical.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
scrollbar_horizontal.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

table.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
body.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
body.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

table.bind('<Button-1>', select_cell)
table.tag_configure('color_1', background='lightgrey')

root.mainloop()
```

You can replace the text with button images.